# Using Google Apps Script to Change the Color of a Cell (based on a "vLookup")

Tags: google-apps-script, gs-vlookup

I have a conference scheduling sheet that is a grid of drop downs with the titles of all the presentations. When a presentation is selected, I'd like it to automatically be set the color of the "type" of presentation it is. Presentation types are found adjacent to the presentation name on another sheet.

I can set the cell color based on contents of the cell, but I'd like that cell value to be looked up in a static, 2-column table (in another location), and an adjacent value returned.

```
function onEdit(event) {

var ss = event.range.getSheet();

if (ss.getName() !== "Sheet2") return;

var changedCell = event.source.getActiveRange();
var c = event.value; 
var color = 'white'; 
var data=getRange('G1:H5').getValues();

for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
if (data[i][0]==c){
  return data[i][1];
}
}

    switch (data[i][1]) {
        case "Math":
            color = "MediumSeaGreen";
            break;
        case "Science":
            color = "Orange";
            break;
        case "History":
            color = "DarkGray";
            break;
        case "English":
            color = "Gold";
            break;
        case "Spanish":
            color = "LightCoral";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

changedCell.setBackground(color);  
}
```

[Image of Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHMwc.png)

Comment: This `if (data[i][0]==c){
  return data[i][1];
}` Terminates the function. And the swtich is outside of the loop.  I would think you would want it inside the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess that this is what you want:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = event.range.getSheet();
  if (ss.getName() !== "Sheet2") return;
  var changedCell = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var c = event.value; 
  var color = 'white'; 
  var data=ss.getRange('G1:H5').getValues();
  for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    if (data[i][0]==c){
      switch (data[i][1]) {
        case "Math":
          color = "MediumSeaGreen";
          break;
        case "Science":
          color = "Orange";
          break;
        case "History":
          color = "DarkGray";
          break;
        case "English":
          color = "Gold";
          break;
        case "Spanish":
          color = "LightCoral";
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      changedCell.setBackground(color);
    }
  } 
}
```

> Note: I haven't tested it.

Comment: Hi @Cooper, THANK YOU!  (and for posterity, I had to add "ss" before the getRange)